# How to sync application engineers (Postgres) with data engineers (Redshift) on schema

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, etl

I work as a data engineer at a mid-sized web company. We have a daily ETL that brings the data over from our application databases (which happen to be Cassandra and Postgres) and store it in our data warehouse (Redshift).

Our current data transfer system is set up in the relatively straightforward following way (for our Postgres DB): we have a read replica of the Postgres DB that we use to load the incremental data to S3 and then copy it to the Redshift tables.

The code that runs this data transfer is on the data team's repository, entirely separate from the application repository.

We are often faced with the following problem: the application-side developers make a change to the schema. They change a column name, they change a constraint, they add a column, etc. They do not inform us about these. These changes sometimes break our ETL process (on QA, but still), and we have to immediately remedy the problem, playing catch-up.

We are spending effort to improve communication, to try and ensure that the application engineers are aware that changes they make must be communicated to us before they go out. However, it seems to me that there must be a better way to solve this problem. Is there a programmatic way to solve it? Could we have an additional shared repository with the developers that runs these transfer scripts? Thus both sides would have to approve the changes for them to go through.

How do other organizations solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the business goals of the datawarehouse. Does it have to contain all the details, change the column types, add new columns, etc - i.e. should it immediately follow the application database?

In most cases it should not, but the data warehouse provides a different view of the data. So let's explicitly add this to our processes: create a view on top of application database with fixed output schema. Make application engineers maintain this view and test it is compatible when they change the schema. If the view is working, the datawarehouse engineers get little surprises.

Of course the data warehouse evolves too, and periodically should add new columns from application database, etc. Each of these evolutions is a small project shared between application and datawarehouse engineers. It starts by defining a new view that includes new data. Once this is done, datawarehouse engineers pick it up, test the view, and adjust their processes to ingest data using new view. During such project the production code is still using the old view, once everything is done, the production switches to new code that uses new view. The old view is retired after that.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like it might be just what we need. Do you have any recommendations for specifically how to enforce the fixed output schema?

Comment: Do you have infrastucture to run query tests, which are run when application developers do their changes? I would just create a query test that executes the view and validates the column types. Comment this test that if there are type changes, the view needs to be updated. 
Don't use * in the view definition - use explicit field names, this detects problem of field renames, etc.